# How to test if one object A intersects and is therefore partly or wholly inside object B

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have the world point positions of two objects, and would like to test if there is an intersection between the two objects from this information.

What methods can I use to test this, especially at the boundaries.

Comment: How are the objects represented? Surfaces modeled with triangles?

Comment: Yes, they are triangular poly meshes.

Comment: approximate (conservative or not ?) or exact ? GPU assisted of pure CPU ? rigid object or deformable ? are the 2 objects arbitrary complex or at least one of both has a simple shape ?

Comment: Minkowski portal refinement and also GJK  are algorithms commonly used for this.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need exact triangle - triangle intersection test that is do you need to know exactly the points of intersection of each object? If you just need a simple yes / no they have intersected then you could get away with creating an AABB ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume ) that encompasses each object and do a AABB -> AABB ( good info here https://studiofreya.com/3d-math-and-physics/simple-aabb-vs-aabb-collision-detection/ ) intersection test? even if you need a more complex collision check Triangle -> Triangle it is always a good idea to do a simple collision check first to make sure its worth doing the complex Triangle -> Triangle intersection tests. Look here ( http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html ) for all the normal object -> object intersection tests you could possibly need